# How a column can be shifted behind using python script node in Knime?

Tags: python, date, data-manipulation, knime

Scenario:

1. The data will be in descending order of date
2. First column will have Texts as fixed headers
3. Next column onwards, the daily date wise will be available
4. For the current month, there should be all days. But from the historical day-wise data, only the last day of that particular month should be available.
5. At the end of current month, the last day should be moved back along with the previous monthly historical data

Before refresh:

After the difference column, there will be daily data of 36 months

| Product | 06/02/2023 | 06/01/2023 | Difference | 05/31/2023 | 05/30/2023 | 05/29/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 576 | (06/02/2023)-(06/01/2023) | 78857 | 3958 | 23 |
| B | 267 | 543 | (06/02/2023)-(06/01/2023) | 234 | 345 | 45 |
| C | 2423 | 768 | (06/02/2023)-(06/01/2023) | 245 | 68 | 76 |

After refresh:

After the difference column, there should be only last day of the previous 36 months.

| Product | 06/03/2023 | 06/02/2023 | Difference | 05/31/2023 | 04/28/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3498 | 100 | (06/03/2023)-(06/02/2023) | 78857 | 566 |
| B | 67 | 267 | (06/03/2023)-(06/02/2023) | 234 | 75 |
| C | 23 | 2423 | (06/03/2023)-(06/02/2023) | 245 | 566 |